# Do I need to preinstall anything before install paho-mqtt in python2.7?

Tags: python, mqtt

I want to install paho-mqtt in python2.

And I am sure that I have already upgraded my Linux os system in raspberry pi.

(The system I use is ubuntu mate 16.04)

I typed the command `pip install paho-mqtt` in terminal, but it still not works.

It shows the error

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirment paho-mqtt(from versions:)
No matching distribution found for paho-mqtt
```

I have also tried to change the official operation system(raspbian), but it still shows error.

Comment: Have you tried `pip2 install paho-mqtt`?

Comment: It is success. I typed "sudo pip install paho-mqtt", but I tried so many times with this command.